# Graph with vertex chromatic number greater than edge chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

is it possible to find a graph whose vertex chromatic number = 2010 + edge chromatic number? And how to prove it?

Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertex chromatic number can't exceed the edge chromatic number by more than $1$.

Let $\chi$ be the vertex chromatic number, $\chi'$ the edge chromatic number. You can get $\chi(G)=\chi'(G)+1$ by taking $G=K_{2n}$.

If $\Delta$ is the maximum degree, then $\chi(G)\le\Delta(G)+1\le\chi'(G)+1$.